# YML file to run JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit, yaml

I am learning how to set up a CI server, part of it is making a .yml file. All I want to do is for it to build my simple Java project and run the Junit tests giving me the results. I have tried a bunch of different ways to implement this but nothing is working.

.yml

```
language: java
jdk:
 - oraclejdk7
script: java TestRunner
```

TestRunner.java

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ForwardingListTest.class);

      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }     
      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

The CI server is giving me `Error: Could not find or load main class TestRunner` error, which does not make sense because TestRunner has a main method.

Any help on how I can fix the .yml file to execute junit test would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously you need to compile your Java code before you can run it:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
script:
  - javac TestRunner
  - java TestRunner
```

As you use JUnit, you will also need to have that in your classpath. For a minimal setup, you could put the necessary jars besides your code and use

```
java -classpath junit.jar;hamcrest-core.jar TestRunner
```

but I seriously advice to rather use a dependency management system like maven or gradle.

Comment: What is the 'hamcrest-core.jar'?

Comment: A [matcher library](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) which JUnit depends on. It is available along with the [JUnit jar](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install).